# Can't figure why my dynamically concatenation of JSX elements doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

How can I dynamically create JSX elements, such that some of the string is bold and some is code? For some reason my algorithm doesn't really works.

In other words, I receive a string that looks like this:

```
Hello *Stackoveflow*, I try to do `React.js` today.
```

I try to dynamically parse this string and make it looks like this:

Hello **Stackoveflow**, I try to do `React.js` today.

---

For some reason it doesn't work.
I parse my string & try to return the `JSX` element I created:

```
export const Description = (props) => {
  const description = props.currentDescription.toString();

  let descriptionContent = "";

  let stringFlag = true;
  let stringContent = "";
  let codeFlag = false;
  let codeContent = "";
  let boldFlag = false;
  let boldContent = "";
  let char = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
    char = description[i];

    if (char === "`") {
      codeFlag = !codeFlag;

      if (codeFlag) {
        stringFlag = false;
        descriptionContent += stringContent;
        stringContent = "";
      } else {
        descriptionContent += <code>{codeContent}</code>;
        stringFlag = true;
        codeContent = "";
      }
    } else if (char === "*") {
      boldFlag = !boldFlag;

      if (boldFlag) {
        stringFlag = false;
        descriptionContent += stringContent;
        stringContent = "";
      } else {
        descriptionContent += <b>{boldContent}</b>;
        stringFlag = true;
        boldContent = "";
      }
    } else {
      if (codeFlag) {
        codeContent += char;
      }

      if (boldFlag) {
        boldContent += char;
      }

      if (stringFlag) {
        stringContent += char;
      }
    }
  }
  stringFlag = false;
  descriptionContent += stringContent;
  stringContent = "";

  return <li className="description">{descriptionContent}</li>;
};
```

However, in return, I receive this result:

```
Hello [Object object], I try to do [Object object] today.
```

Could anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concat (`+=`) JSX as they are objects. By using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you can render the HTML elements from a string (but only HTML elements, not components).

So this fix should work:

```
<li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: descriptionContent }} />
```

Notice that its a usecase for Regex, so you can simplify the logic much more:

```
const generateReplacer = (regex, element) => (match) => {
  const fixedWord = match.replaceAll(regex, "");
  return `<${element}>${fixedWord}</${element}>`;
};

export const Description = (props) => {
  const description = props.currentDescription;

  return (
    <div className="description">
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: description
            .replace(/\*.+\*/, generateReplacer("*", "strong"))
            .replace(/`.+`/, generateReplacer("`", "code"))
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit zealous-fermi-bm765]

I suggest checking markdown-to-html libraries that already implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to create an array of JSX elements from the string instead of concatenating the string together.

```
export const Description = (props) => {
  const description = props.currentDescription.toString();

  let descriptionContent = [];

  let stringFlag = true;
  let stringContent = "";
  let codeFlag = false;
  let codeContent = "";
  let boldFlag = false;
  let boldContent = "";
  let char = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
    char = description[i];

    if (char === "`") {
      codeFlag = !codeFlag;

      if (codeFlag) {
        stringFlag = false;
        descriptionContent.push(stringContent);
        stringContent = "";
      } else {
        descriptionContent.push(<code>{codeContent}</code>);
        stringFlag = true;
        codeContent = "";
      }
    } else if (char === "*") {
      boldFlag = !boldFlag;

      if (boldFlag) {
        stringFlag = false;
        descriptionContent.push(stringContent);
        stringContent = "";
      } else {
        descriptionContent.push(<b>{boldContent}</b>);
        stringFlag = true;
        boldContent = "";
      }
    } else {
      if (codeFlag) {
        codeContent += char;
      }

      if (boldFlag) {
        boldContent += char;
      }

      if (stringFlag) {
        stringContent += char;
      }
    }
  }
  stringFlag = false;
  descriptionContent.push(stringContent);
  stringContent = "";

  return <li className="description">{descriptionContent}</li>;
};
```

[See demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-fermat-rzgun?file=/src/Description.js)